# Infinite Redirect When Trying Short URLs with Mediawiki (Apache + Nginx-reverse-proxy)

Tags: apache, nginx, mediawiki

Been having this problem for months, I just cannot fix it. I have Mediawiki 1.31.1 with PHP 7.1.26 on Apache using Nginx as a reverse proxy

Everything works...

Except when changing configs for short URLs. Followed the Mediawiki short URL guide, and any method results in an infinite redirect error (tried many methods). Tried changing PHP versions and that didnt seem to do anything either.

relevant configs:

nginx reverse-proxy

```
   server {
        listen   80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name _;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
         }
         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
    }
```

Apache config (at end of httpd.conf)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

Mediawiki Localsettings.php settings

```
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgEnableUploads  = true;
$wgGenerateThumbnailOnParse = false;
```

Comment: I have the same issue following this guide: https://techwelkin.com/mediawiki-urls-short-clean-and-beautiful
With the real path being /wiki and $wgScriptPath = "/asdf", it redirects to /asdf. With it being /wiki it redirects to ... /wiki, infinitely.